# Selecting the Lag and then Aggregating the Data to Control Chart Autocorrelated Extrusion Data?

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, quality-control

I have wall thickness data from an extruded product. I understand that for use in a control chart (XmR) that data from extruded products will be autocorrelated. My data was sampled every 5 seconds which resulted in 4,804 data points for this example. When I use the acf function in R I get the following result:

[image: acf default lag]

Lag 11 is the first below the 0.05 threshold. For use in a control chart, do I grab every 11th data point from my data set or do I find the mean for every 11 data points? Or do I not understand this at all? Also, because of the sinusoidal pattern I reran acf at higher lags to see the overall pattern. Here is acf at a lag of 1200:

[image: acf lag = 1200]

From some other posts I learned that there is likely a seasonal component and a unit root component to the data. Is that significant to control charting the data or only if I was trying to model the process using an autoregressive model?